# Is there an application that can monitor the network and API usage of an .exe?

Tags: monitoring, traffic

Is there an application that can monitor the network and API usage of an .exe ?

I am looking for an app that can monitor:
- Network traffic and or just HTTP traffic
- Windows API calls

For a delphi exe which I do not have the source for.

Any suggestions.

Thankyou.

Comment: For monitoring file and registry activity, Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For monitoring network traffic, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is *the* tool. It allows you to analyze traffic down to the Ethernet level, or up to the HTTP level, as you desire.

For monitoring API calls, there exists [API Monitor](http://www.apimonitor.com/), but it's not free and I have no experience with it. However, since all API functions come from some DLL, you can also use a tool that monitors calls into DLLs; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311268/monitoring-application-calls-to-dll) has more on that subject.

Comment: Agreed that Wireshark is very good. For specifically HTTP traffic I prefer Fiddler tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/. Though Trend Micro is blocking the site for me at the moment as "Dangerous", I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it can monitor HTTP traffic of all running applications, you can view or change the response of any HTTP request.

to monitor windows api calls check out [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy).