# Cannot install MySQL UDF

Tags: mysql, dll, java-native-interface

I have created a MySQL UDF that calls Java functions using JNI. MS Visual Studio compiles my code without any problems and generates a DLL for my 64bit MySQL Server (v.5.5). 
Here is what the C/C++ code looks like:

```
#ifdef STANDARD
/* STANDARD is defined, don't use any mysql functions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __WIN__
typedef unsigned __int64 ulonglong;/* Microsofts 64 bit types */
typedef __int64 longlong;
#else
typedef unsigned long long ulonglong;
typedef long long longlong;
#endif /*__WIN__*/
#else
#include <my_global.h>
#include <my_sys.h>
#if defined(MYSQL_SERVER)
#include <m_string.h>/* To get strmov() */
#else
/* when compiled as standalone */
#include <string.h>
#define strmov(a,b) stpcpy(a,b)
#define bzero(a,b) memset(a,0,b)
#define memcpy_fixed(a,b,c) memcpy(a,b,c)
#endif
#endif
#include <mysql.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
/* inet_aton needs winsock library */
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_DLOPEN

#if !defined(HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R) || !defined(HAVE_SOLARIS_STYLE_GETHOST)
static pthread_mutex_t LOCK_hostname;
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXP
#endif

#include <jni.h>

DLLEXP my_bool call_java_method_init(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)),    UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
DLLEXP void call_java_method_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)));
DLLEXP char* call_java_method(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)), UDF_ARGS *args,
                     char* is_null __attribute__((unused)),   char* error __attribute__((unused)));

 static JNIEnv *env;
 static JavaVM *jvm;

 JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM **jvm) {
   JNIEnv *env;
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
   JavaVMOption options;
   options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaApps\\CallJavaFromC++\\bin"; //Path to the java source code
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.options = &options;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

   int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
   if(ret < 0)
      printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");       
  return env;
 }


my_bool call_java_method_init(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)), UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
if(!(args->arg_count == 3)) {
    char *m = "Expected 3 arguments. Function usage: call_java_method('classPath', 'className', 'methodName(methodArguments)') ";
    strcpy_s(message,  strlen(m)+1, m);
    return 1;
}

env = create_vm(&jvm);
if (env == NULL){
    char *m = "Could not load JVM!";
    strcpy_s(message,  strlen(m)+1, m);
    return 1;
}


args->arg_type[0] = STRING_RESULT;  
args->arg_type[1] = STRING_RESULT;
args->arg_type[2] = STRING_RESULT;

return 0;
}

void call_java_method_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)))
{
int n = jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}

char* call_java_method(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)), UDF_ARGS *args,
                     char* is_null __attribute__((unused)), char* error __attribute__((unused)))
{
char* retResult = "";

jclass clsLEC = NULL;
jmethodID callJavaClass = NULL;
jstring jstrcalljava = NULL;
const char *pResult = NULL;

clsLEC = env->FindClass("LoadExternalClass");
if(clsLEC != NULL)
{
    callJavaClass = env->GetStaticMethodID(clsLEC,"callJavaClass","([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
}
else
    {
    printf("\nUnable to find the requested class\n");       
    }
if(clsLEC != NULL && callJavaClass != NULL)
{
    jobjectArray ret= (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(3, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), env->NewStringUTF(""));
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,0,env->NewStringUTF(args->args[0]));
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,1,env->NewStringUTF(args->args[1]));
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,2,env->NewStringUTF(args->args[2]));

    jstrcalljava = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clsLEC,callJavaClass,ret); 
    pResult = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstrcalljava,0);   
    retResult = _strdup(pResult);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstrcalljava,pResult);
}
//Release resources.    
return retResult;
}

#endif /* HAVE_DLOPEN */
```

I've dropped the **MySQLJavaUDF.dll** file into the MySQL plugins folder. In order to verify that the file is compiled for a 64bit OS I've used the *PE Deconstructor* programmed by a stackoverflow member ([How can I test a Windows DLL file to determine if it is 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)).
 

Then I also checked whether the DLL contains all required functions by executing Visual Studios *dumpbin /EXPORTS* command. The output looks as follows and seems to be correct:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for MySQLJavaUDF.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    531F74A1 time date stamp Tue Mar 11 21:40:01 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           3 number of functions
           3 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001150 ?call_java_method@@YAPEADPEAUst_udf_init@@PEAUst_udf_a
rgs@@PEAD2@Z = ?call_java_method@@YAPEADPEAUst_udf_init@@PEAUst_udf_args@@PEAD2@
Z (char * __cdecl call_java_method(struct st_udf_init *,struct st_udf_args *,cha
r *,char *))
          2    1 00001140 ?call_java_method_deinit@@YAXPEAUst_udf_init@@@Z = ?ca
ll_java_method_deinit@@YAXPEAUst_udf_init@@@Z (void __cdecl call_java_method_dei
nit(struct st_udf_init *))
          3    2 000010B0 ?call_java_method_init@@YADPEAUst_udf_init@@PEAUst_udf
_args@@PEAD@Z = ?call_java_method_init@@YADPEAUst_udf_init@@PEAUst_udf_args@@PEA
D@Z (char __cdecl call_java_method_init(struct st_udf_init *,struct st_udf_args
*,char *))

  Summary

        4000 .data
        2000 .pdata
        9000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        5000 .rsrc
       22000 .text
```

Then I've made the first attempt to install the UDF by typing the following command in the MySQL Browser:

```
CREATE FUNCTION call_java_method
RETURNS STRING
SONAME 'MySQLJavaUDF.dll';
```

The installation failed with error 1126:
**Can't open shared library 'MySQLJavaUDF.dll' (errno: 126 The specified module could not be found.)**
So I've downloaded the Process Monitor to see what happens when installing the DLL file as suggested in the post [Monitoring application calls to DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311268/monitoring-application-calls-to-dll) 
It turned out that the **jvm.dll** could not be found. OK, copied the file from my Java 1.6.45 64bit installation folder into the MySQL Server/bin folder, executed the SQL command again and got again a "NAME NOT FOUND" result from Procmon regarding a **WINMM.dll** file. No problem, copied and pasted the file in question from my Windows/System32 directory into the bin folder. This time Procmon only reported "SUCCESS" results, but now MySQL complains with error 1127, telling me it
**Can't find symbol 'call_java_method' in library**
.
And here is where I'm stuck and gave up. Maybe one of you experts have any ideas about what is going wrong. I suspect that the DLL cannot load the JVM for some reason. I also think that copying the jvm.dll into the bin folder is not the right approach.

My system:
**Windows 7 64bit**
**MySQL Server 5.5 64bit**
**Java 1.6.45 64bit**
**MS Visual Studio 2012 (using x64 solution platform)**

Comment: OK solved it. I had to encapsulate the functions within this code block **extern "C" { ... }** since I'm using C++ and not C (see also [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html)). And now it "finds the symbol"

Answer (score 0):

mysql understands only C-like names of functions. You need to export of such names obviously:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#define DLLEXP extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

And just in case try to compile your dll with flags, with which mysql was compiled on your platform. For this use `mysql_config` utility from mysql distribution like this:

```
mysql_config --cxxflags
```

So you will be able to define necessary compilation flags.