# How to know which dll is related to which asp page

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have one project that I imported from somewhere. How would I know which dll is being called on form submit click.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Their is nothing wrong in your question , Question is perfectly ok, But already  their will be  a discussion about this topic in stack overflow check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311268/monitoring-application-calls-to-dll

Comment: @ArunPrasanth thank you I'll try it and let you know